# How to clear cache, reload current page in a given time?

Tags: php, jquery, yii

how to clear the cache and auto reload page in a given time  in yii framework ?
like e.g in the next 5 hours, the content of the page should change prior to clear cache then reload the page

```
$time = date('h:i:s A', strtotime("+5 hours"));
```

and then in the next 5 hours, it will clear cache again and reload the same page and show new content

Comment: Do you mean yii's cache? What cache you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand well the question.

In the Yii view that your are, add something like this in javascript

```
<script>
 setTimeout(function(){ window.location = "<URL>";}, 5*60*1000);
</script>
```

this is a redirect after 5 minutes. if you want 5 hours just use

```
300*60*1000
```

and point the URL to www.example.com/controller/action you want.

If still you wanna do it in php i believe you can add this line to your view.

```
<?php header("Refresh: 18000; URL=http://www.example.com/controller/action"); ?>
```

here 18000 is in seconds.

Hope it helps.

but if you are only updating small bits of the view.. why not create a timer to make ajax request to the controller/action you want to update the data from? Yii is ready for that kind of need.

Comment: how bout the clear cache ?, because the page itself is being cache in the yii framewokr

Comment: if the data have changed Yii and the cache system you are using will know it. try the above example on a shorter timeframe say 2 minutes. and see if it works. aren't we confusing server-side cache with users browser cache, aren't we?!

Comment: what cache component are you using in Yii ? CMemCache?